# How to set bin coordinates for a scatter plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram, scatter

I want to return the number of scatter points that occupy a specific area. Normally, I would do this by using a `2dhistogram` and `pcolormesh`.

But if I wanted to set bin coordinates that represented irregular sizes that don't represent a grid, how would I do this?

Below is an example of my dataset.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import math
import numpy as np

x1 = np.random.randint(80, size=(400, 10))
y1 = np.random.randint(80, size=(400, 10))

x2 = np.random.randint(80, size=(400, 10))
y2 = np.random.randint(80, size=(400, 10))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.grid(False)

plt.scatter(x1[0],y1[0], c = 'r', zorder = 2)
plt.scatter(x2[0],y2[0], c = 'b', zorder = 2)

ang1 = 0, 50
ang2 = 100, 50
angle = math.degrees(math.acos(5.5/9.15))
xy = 50, 50

Halfway = mpl.lines.Line2D((50,50), (0,100), c = 'white')
arc1 = mpl.patches.Arc(ang1, 65, 100, angle = 0, theta2 = angle, theta1 = 360-angle, lw = 2)
arc2 = mpl.patches.Arc(ang2, 65, 100, angle = 0, theta2 = 180+angle, theta1 = 180-angle, lw = 2)
Oval = mpl.patches.Ellipse(xy, 100, 100, lw = 3, alpha = 0.1)

ax.add_line(Halfway)
ax.add_patch(arc1)
ax.add_patch(arc2)
ax.add_patch(Oval)

plt.text(15, 75, '1', fontsize = 8)
plt.text(35, 90, '2', fontsize = 8)
plt.text(65, 90, '3', fontsize = 8)
plt.text(85, 75, '4', fontsize = 8)

ax.autoscale()

plt.draw()
```

The bins I want to set are labelled 1-4. Is it possible to set coordinates that return those bins?

If I can set these coordinates, I then want to return the bin that each scatter point occupies.
Output:

[image]

Update:

If I wanted an export that displayed xy's in each bin for each row in the scatter plot I would write out `(x1[0], y1[0])` and transpose the data to return:

```
          1             2            3             4   
0  [(x,y),(x,y)] [(x,y),(x,y)] [(x,y),(x,y)] [(x,y),(x,y)]
```

Then I would change `(x1[0], y1[0])` to `(x1[1], y1[1])` to get the second row of data.

```
          1             2            3             4   
1  [(x,y),(x,y)] [(x,y),(x,y)] [(x,y),(x,y)] [(x,y),(x,y)]
```

Then I would combine those to create:

```
          1             2            3             4   
0  [(x,y),(x,y)] [(x,y),(x,y)] [(x,y),(x,y)] [(x,y),(x,y)]  
1  [(x,y),(x,y)] [(x,y),(x,y)] [(x,y),(x,y)] [(x,y),(x,y)]
```

I've got 1000's of rows so I'm trying to create a method to use the entire `(x1, y1)` to produce the coordinates in each bin for each row of data.

Intended Output:

```
          1             2            3             4   
0  [(x,y),(x,y)] [(x,y),(x,y)] [(x,y),(x,y)] [(x,y),(x,y)]
1  [(x,y),(x,y)] [(x,y),(x,y)] [(x,y),(x,y)] [(x,y),(x,y)]
2  [(x,y),(x,y)] [(x,y),(x,y)] [(x,y),(x,y)] [(x,y),(x,y)]    
3  [(x,y),(x,y)] [(x,y),(x,y)] [(x,y),(x,y)] [(x,y),(x,y)]
4  [(x,y),(x,y)] [(x,y),(x,y)] [(x,y),(x,y)] [(x,y),(x,y)]
5....
6....
```

If I try `(x1, y1)` I get the error:

`err = (arc_vertices[:,0] - x)**2 + (arc_vertices[:,1] - y)**2 ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (70,) (10,)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm really not happy with this approach.  Calculating where the y coordinate for a point with your data's x coordinate would fall on the curve seems better.

This approach works similarly, but uses the arc's finite vertices:

```
arc1v = ax.transData.inverted().transform(arc1.get_verts())
arc2v = ax.transData.inverted().transform(arc2.get_verts())

for (x,y) in zip(x1[0], y1[0]):
    err = (arc1v[:,0] - x)**2 + (arc1v[:,1] - y)**2
    nearest = (arc1v[err == min(err)])[0]
    line_x = (x, nearest[0])
    line_y = (y, nearest[1])
    ax.add_line(mpl.lines.Line2D(line_x, line_y))

    if x > nearest[0]:
        ax.scatter(x, y, marker='^', s=100, c='k', zorder=1)
    else:
        ax.scatter(x, y, marker='v', s=100, c='k', zorder=1)
```

This "labels" points on the left of the (left) curve with a down-facing triangle and points on the right of it with an up-facing triangle.  The lines on the graph point to the nearest defined vertex on the curve and are for illustration only.

You could do this for the other curve as well, and the bin 2/3 division is straightforward.

Here's an example output figure:
[image]

### Update:

Here's a more complete answer:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import math
import numpy as np


BIN_23_X = 50               # The separator between bin 2 and 3

x1 = np.random.randint(80, size=(400, 10))
y1 = np.random.randint(80, size=(400, 10))

x2 = np.random.randint(80, size=(400, 10))
y2 = np.random.randint(80, size=(400, 10))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.grid(False)

plt.scatter(x1[0],y1[0], c = 'r', zorder = 2)
plt.scatter(x2[0],y2[0], c = 'b', zorder = 2)

ang1 = 0, 50
ang2 = 100, 50
angle = math.degrees(math.acos(5.5/9.15))
xy = 50, 50

Halfway = mpl.lines.Line2D((BIN_23_X,BIN_23_X), (0,100), c = 'white')
arc1 = mpl.patches.Arc(ang1, 65, 100, angle = 0, theta2 = angle, theta1 = 360-angle, lw = 2)
arc2 = mpl.patches.Arc(ang2, 65, 100, angle = 0, theta2 = 180+angle, theta1 = 180-angle, lw = 2)
Oval = mpl.patches.Ellipse(xy, 100, 100, lw = 3, alpha = 0.1)

ax.add_line(Halfway)
ax.add_patch(arc1)
ax.add_patch(arc2)
ax.add_patch(Oval)

plt.text(15, 75, '1', fontsize = 8)
plt.text(35, 90, '2', fontsize = 8)
plt.text(65, 90, '3', fontsize = 8)
plt.text(85, 75, '4', fontsize = 8)

# Classification helpers
def get_nearest_arc_vert(x, y, arc_vertices):
    err = (arc_vertices[:,0] - x)**2 + (arc_vertices[:,1] - y)**2
    nearest = (arc_vertices[err == min(err)])[0]
    return nearest

arc1v = ax.transData.inverted().transform(arc1.get_verts())
arc2v = ax.transData.inverted().transform(arc2.get_verts())

def classify_pointset(vx, vy):
    bins = {(k+1):[] for k in range(4)}
    for (x,y) in zip(vx, vy):
        nx1, ny1 = get_nearest_arc_vert(x, y, arc1v)
        nx2, ny2 = get_nearest_arc_vert(x, y, arc2v)

        if x < nx1:                         # Is this point in bin 1?  To the left of arc1?
            bins[1].append((x,y))
        elif x > nx2:                       # Is this point in bin 4?  To the right of arc2?
            bins[4].append((x,y))
        else:
            # If we get here, the point is in either bin 2 or 3.  We'll consider points
            #   that fall on the line to be in bin 3.
            if x < BIN_23_X:                # Is this point to the left BIN_23_X? => Bin 2
                bins[2].append((x,y))
            else:                           # Otherwise, the point is in Bin 3
                bins[3].append((x,y))

    return bins

# Classify points
bins_red  = classify_pointset(x1[0], y1[0])
bins_blue = classify_pointset(x2[0], y2[0])

# Display classifications
print("Red:")
for x in bins_red.items():
    print(" ", x)

print("Blue:")
for x in bins_blue.items():
    print(" ", x)

# "Annotate" classifications
for (x,y) in (bins_red[1] + bins_blue[1]):
    ax.scatter(x, y, marker='^', s=100, c='k', zorder=1)

for (x,y) in (bins_red[2] + bins_blue[2]):
    ax.scatter(x, y, marker='v', s=100, c='k', zorder=1)

for (x,y) in (bins_red[3] + bins_blue[3]):
    ax.scatter(x, y, marker='^', s=100, c='y', zorder=1)

for (x,y) in (bins_red[4] + bins_blue[4]):
    ax.scatter(x, y, marker='v', s=100, c='y', zorder=1)


ax.autoscale()

plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

Produces:

[image]

Here, points are "annotated" with shapes behind them corresponding to which bins they were classified into:

```
Bin       Anno. Color     Triangle Pointing
-------------------------------------------
Bin 1     Black           Up
Bin 2     Black           Down
Bin 3     Yellow          Up
Bin 4     Yellow          Down
```

The code also displays the classification results (the output of `classify_pointset` is a dict, keyed on bin number (1-4) with the values being the point coordinates of points found to be in the bin:

```
Red:
  (1, [(14, 30), (4, 18), (12, 48)])
  (2, [(49, 41)])
  (3, [(62, 79), (50, 7), (68, 19), (71, 1), (59, 27), (77, 0)])
  (4, [])
Blue:
  (1, [(20, 74), (11, 17), (12, 75)])
  (2, [(41, 19), (30, 15)])
  (3, [(61, 75)])
  (4, [(79, 73), (69, 58), (76, 34), (78, 65)])
```

You don't have to annotate the figure graphically, it's just there for illustration, you can just use the dicts returned by `classify_pointset` (`bins_red` and `bins_blue`).

### Update 2

The following code produces a list of lists (still 1-indexed), so you can find all the points (both red and blue) in bin 1 by accessing `all_points[1]`.  The first element (index 0) in the `all_points` list is `None`, since we're keeping the list 1-indexed.

```
# Generate a list of lists, the outer index corresponds to the bin number (1-indexed)
all_points = [None] * 5
for bin_key in [1,2,3,4]:
    all_points[bin_key] = bins_red[bin_key] + bins_blue[bin_key]

# Just for display.
for bin_key, bin_points in enumerate(all_points):
    print(bin_key, bin_points)
```

Output:

```
0 None
1 [(1, 8), (16, 72), (23, 67), (12, 19), (24, 51), (24, 47), (15, 23), (18, 51)]
2 [(39, 75), (35, 27), (48, 55), (45, 53), (45, 22)]
3 [(66, 58), (55, 64), (70, 1), (71, 15), (73, 3), (71, 75)]
4 [(74, 62)]
```

Comment: This is good @jedwards. If I included the division for bins 2-3 and replicated the code for bin 4, could I technically return the bin number from any particular scatter point? Or would this have to be additionally coded

Comment: You could, just repeat the logic in the for loop for your (x,y) point.  Inside the loop, each datapoint is defined by `x` and `y`, so it should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: I can get the second line displayed to bin 4 but unsure how I would split 2/3 and actually return which bins each point is in @jedwards. Thanks for your help though

Comment: @Maxibon Splitting 2/3 is pretty straightforward.  See the updated the post for a more complete answer.

Comment: Thanks @jedwards. I have to wait 18hrs for the bounty sorry.

Comment: No worries, esp. if a better answer pops up!

Comment: This answer is brilliant

Comment: sorry to be a pain. I was wondering if I could convert each row of `xy data` to a list of lists or the count of coordinates in each bin into a `df`. So using the above example, Red would have 3 in Bin 1, 1 in Bin 2, 6 in Bin 3, 0 in Bin 4.

Comment: I can get a count for each bin using `f = {k: len(v) for k,v in dict.items()}` but I would have to go through each row to export this `(x1[0], y1[0])`

Comment: @Maxibon are you still interested in preserving what "color" the (x,y) point is?  In otherwords, do you want a single list of both colors, or two lists (e.g. `xy_data_red` and `xy_data_blue`)?

Comment: If possible a single list of both colours would be great. They represent two diff entities.

Comment: @Maxibon let me know if the Update 2 section works for you, or if not, what you need differently.

Comment: Thanks @jedwards. Hopefully the last edit I'm asking for. I've changed the question to provide a visual description. I'm hoping to export the coordinates and bins for each row in the scatter plot. So separated via frames. Thanks for all your help!